# How to retrieve object from child_process stdout?

Tags: node.js, instance, child-process

I want to run some `process` on different instance than `Node` server. I'm trying with child_process, I create some loop and execute `child_process`.

From child_process, I retrieve as `Buffer` and In object format like follow.

```
{ data: [], status: 'active', success: true }
```

How should I get these data as an object format?

```
const child = spawn('node', ['app.js']); 
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    // How can I apply filter over to ignore some data
    console.log(data)   // print buffer
    console.log(data.toString())   // print some stringify Obj
});
```

Is there any way we can send data for `child_process` from `app.js` except `console.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If app.js is a node script it's easy to send data to the caller (and vice-versa) for example:

**index.js**

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const appInstance = child_process.fork('app.js', [], {});
appInstance.on('message', message => {
    console.log('Message from app.js:', message, JSON.stringify(message));
});
```

**app.js**

```
// Send some data to caller. 
const data = { status: 'ok', message: 'hello from app.js' };
if (process.send) {
    process.send(data);
}
```

If you want to filter there are loads of ways of doing this. In the message handler you can switch on the *message* object, e.g. if (message && message.status).

Comment: What is server requirement for running `100 child_process` single time?